# Is there a way to make only certain sizes of an image download through css?

Tags: html, css, scripting, photo, photos

Basically what I am asking is, is there a way to have say a 1000x1000 pixel image and simply have some sort of code, whether html, css, or anything else to only download a resized verison of 100x100 pixels. Is there any way to do this? I would like to know before resizing each of my pictures and uploading them and linking those photos to the original larger version. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do it with HTML/CSS but it is possible with a server side language like PHP.  [Here's a script](http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/) that will allow you to resize images.

The catch is that resizing images can be a server intensive process.  You should try to make sure that once you've created a resized version of an image, it's cached on the server for subsequent requests.

Along those lines, the flow should be:

1. Image request comes in.
2. Does the resized thumbnail exist in the server's cache?  If yes, serve the thumbnail.
3. If no, create the thumbnail, place it in the server cache and serve it.

**Note:** James brought up a good point in the comments.  If the images you're resizing are going to change (updated/edited), you'll need to keep track of their large image's last modified date when you create the thumbnail (as part of the filename or in a database).

That way, when you check the cache, you'll be able to tell if the thumbnail needs to be regenerated.

Comment: just curious here (I'm not the poster of the question), but could you also in theory save such image to your server and serve up that version to other browsers rather than re-sizing it for every request from a unique IP + browser? (EDIT or do you mean cached on the server?)

Comment: Absolutely - that's what I meant by cache.  The resized image is stored in a server cache (usually the server's file system) so that it's available to any following user.  I've updated my answer for clarity.

Comment: fascinating... I really need to learn more server side programming :P

Comment: @Joseph Don't we all? ;) About the server caching: if the images are likely to change (get updated/edited etc.) you'll also want to keep track of that so you know when to update the thumbnails. If not then ignore me ;)

Comment: @James Good point about edited images in the cache - I've added it to my answer.

Comment: @Pat another solution to that might be 1) to remove all thumbnails when it is edited 2) or even add the image's version/has to the querystring eg `image.png?version=number` or `image.png?version=hash` though this would be more if you keep different version or you want the user's cache to update.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an account on imageshack.us (create the account to make sure your images don't get deleted) and then upload the image in different sizes and link to whatever size you want. (You don't have to do the resizing yourself, you can do it on imageshack when you upload) That way you get the image in whatever size you want and without putting any load at all on your server.

That's what I do and it works wonderfully

Example:

http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/1825/lakesunset.jpg

http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6420/lakesunsetf.jpg

Both came directly from imageshack. Just uploaded the image twice and resized one on imageshack.

Then to display the thumbnail and link it to the larger one just use this code:

`<a href="DIRECT LARGE IMAGE URL"><img src="DIRECT SMALL IMAGE URL"/></a>`

Example:

[http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/6420/lakesunsetf.jpg](http://img52.imageshack.us/img52/1825/lakesunset.jpg)

Sorry, I've never done any server side programming since I'm not a professional and I'm poor, so I can't help you if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: What does being poor have to do with server-side programming?

Comment: I can't afford a server? I've been using the same computer for 6 years, I wouldn't even have one if I didn't get it for free. How do you suggest I pracice server side programming without spending any money?